# Internet Explorer 9 Developer tools issue for css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I using IE7 document mode using developer tools in IE9 browser, so that my webpage looks like how it is in IE 7 browser, to fix some issues only in IE 7 i used the below code only for ie7.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I did modifications in ie7.css file and reviewed in ie7 developer tools in ie9 browser ,but no effect comes into existence .
But i view in ie7 browser the effect comes into exist

Comment: Make sure both "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" are set to IE7.

Comment: Obviously i used browser mode and document mode as ie7

Comment: It's only obvious if you tell us. We're not mind readers :)

Comment: Quick note of warning, the IE9 IE7 document mode is NOT a good reflection of the actual IE7 browser. I have IE7 on running on a virtual PC and the different between the IE9 version and the actual browser is massive. Testing in the IE9 other document modes is NOT accurate at all and I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose "Compatibility View" in browser mode to getting the CSS effect for IE7 specific.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're adding !important tag in IE7.css, Otherwise the elements will take rule according to priority.

Example:

```
.home_link{
     color: #EEE !important;
     padding: 15px !important;
}
```